# How can I upgrade iMac with Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) to Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard

I am on a 6-year-old iMac desktop (2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo) running Mac OS X 10.6.8 and Apple’s app store download page gives me an unhelpful error message hinting that I may need to install software to access the download page without saying what software I might need. Could that be software for upgrading software? Do I need to install some intermediate version of Mac OS X before getting to Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)? Can I / should I just upgrade to Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)? Some apps no longer support Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) so I ought to do something.

Recommendations and how to’s very gratefully welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to download the update and then extract the DMG onto a portable, bootable drive. You may need the assistance of someone with 10.10 or 10.9. Either way, there are [many articles available on this process](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20upgrade%20from%2010.6%20to%2010.10&oq=how%20to%20upgrade%20from%2010.6%20to%2010&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l5.10294j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8), courtesy of your friends at Google.

Comment: Don't be so condescending. I spent much time searching and reading articles before posting my question. I have since discovered that the problem is hardware, not software, related. My iMac, purchased in early 2009, came with 1 gig of (not upgradeable) memory and it seems that Yosemite, the only currently available OS X upgrade, won't run with less than two. So the real answer to how can I upgrade is I cannot.

Comment: @user428573 Believe me, I wasn't all all trying to be condescending. This post didn't seem like the right place to outline a detailed, multi-step process that has been written up countless times elsewhere. I'm glad you got to the root of the problem.